# Is there a free Website monitor app?

Tags: software-rec, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any tools to periodically check if a web site is available?](https://superuser.com/questions/19126/are-there-any-tools-to-periodically-check-if-a-web-site-is-available)

I am a developer and I work on a large list of internal websites and want to know if they are down before the user calls me. I've used services like http://aremysitesup.com/ before, but they won't work with internal sites that they can't access or that are HTTPS only websites.

Is there a free tool that will monitor websites for me or is there a code project that I can modify to fit my needs?

Answer (score 1):

There's a project called Cacti that is flexible enough for your needs.  Their forums are a wealth of information and I'm pretty sure someone probably already has a solution for it there.  It may be overkill, but it's a good starting point.

http://www.cacti.net