# Efficient and effective way to batch-test domain names

Tags: networking, domain

The ad-blocker database I’ve been using for years has gotten very bloated over time, and now it is full of lots of obsolete domains (some are not even valid). I want to trim it down, but I am not sure how best to do that.

What I tried was to create a batch file that parses the file and pings each domain, then depending on the errorlevel, writes the domain-name to either the `live` or `dead` file. This is a decent solution, but it has at least a couple of problems:

1. It does not account for servers that discard pings
2. Even with the `-n 1` and `-w 1000` switches, many domains still take 10 seconds to timeout
3. It tests one at a time, so it can take a very long time to finish

Does anyone have any suggestions for how to test whether a list of domain-names are alive? Requirements:

- It doesn’t matter if the solution is command-line or GUI
- I’m not *too* concerned about missing some servers that discard ICMP (time is more important)
- It should not test *too* many at once, or my ISP won’t be happy (preferrably configurable)

Comment: Related/possible dupe: [Are there any tools to periodically check if a web site is available?](http://superuser.com/questions/19126/are-there-any-tools-to-periodically-check-if-a-web-site-is-available)

Comment: While a website-monitor should work (ad-servers don't really serve FTP or whatever), an online tool won’t work because those are meant to continuously monitor one or two domains, not check many domains a single time.

Comment: Don't ping, but do a DNS lookup instead. if the domain blocks ICMP/ECHO or is temporarily down, you won't get a response. Note however that a failure to lookup a DNS name takes at least 2 seconds per try (ping will behave the same, since you are starting with names). The exact tact I'd take depends on the toolchain already in use, with your parser and all.

Comment: @FrankThomas How does doing a DNS lookup confirm the site is actively "alive"?

Comment: @Techie007, the question the op poses, isn't whether the site is alive or not, but whether the entries in the database are still valid. They already acknowledge that a ping is not a valid test for "live", so since we are focused on a database of domain names, testing them seems the wise approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest python? 
Will update this answer with tested code when I get back to my PC but it would look something like

```
import requests
with open("blocklist.txt", "r") as f:
    for n in f.readLines():
        r = requests.get(n)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            m = open("good.txt", "a")
            m.write(n)
            m.close()
        else:
            m = open("bad.txt", "a")
            m.write(n)
            m.close()
```

With blocklist.txt as:

```
google.com
testrgdjhdhdhdhhdh.com
example.com
```

And good.txt:

```
google.com
example.com
```

bad.txt:

```
testrgdjhdhdhdhhdh.com
```